# Derive a number X from five numbers which each have 2 digits right

Tags: python

I wrote the code below which derives a number X, based on an input of 5 numbers in the range from 0 to 9999. These 5 numbers each have two digits which X also has, but their position is wrong (e.g. a digit of X in the thousands position is given in the hundred position).

Example input：

```
6087,5173,1358,3825,2531
```

For this input the expected output is:

```
8712
```

The code below calculates X, but it is brute force. How can I reduce the time complexity?

```
m = ('6087','5173','1358','3825','2531')
x = ['']*5

for i in range(0,5):
    a=int(m[i])/1000
    b=int(m[i])/100-10*a
    c=int(m[i])/10-100*a-10*b
    d=int(m[i])%10
    x[i]=[a,b,c,d]

for num in range(0,10000):
    thousand=num/1000
    hundred=num/100-10*thousand
    decade=num/10-100*thousand-10*hundred
    digits=num%10
    count=0
    for j in range(0,5):
        if (thousand==x[j][1] or thousand==x[j][2] or thousand==x[j][3]) and (hundred==x[j][0] or hundred==x[j][2] or hundred==x[j][3]) and (decade!=x[j][0] and decade!=x[j][1] and decade!=x[j][2] and decade!=x[j][3]) and (digits!=x[j][0] and digits!=x[j][1] and decade!=x[j][2] and decade!=x[j][3]):
            count+=1
        elif (thousand==x[j][1] or thousand==x[j][2] or thousand==x[j][3]) and (decade==x[j][0] or decade==x[j][1] or decade==x[j][3]) and (hundred!=x[j][0] and hundred!=x[j][1] and hundred!=x[j][2] and hundred!=x[j][3]) and (digits!=x[j][0] and digits!=x[j][1] and decade!=x[j][2] and decade!=x[j][3]):
            count+=1
        elif (thousand==x[j][1] or thousand==x[j][2] or thousand==x[j][3]) and (digits==x[j][0] or digits==x[j][1] or digits==x[j][2]) and (hundred!=x[j][0] and hundred!=x[j][1] and hundred!=x[j][2] and hundred!=x[j][3]) and  (decade!=x[j][0] and decade!=x[j][1] and decade!=x[j][2] and decade!=x[j][3]):
            count+=1
        elif (hundred==x[j][0] or hundred==x[j][2] or hundred==x[j][3]) and (decade==x[j][0] or decade==x[j][1] or decade==x[j][3]) and (thousand!=x[j][0] and thousand!=x[j][1] and thousand!=x[j][2] and thousand!=x[j][3]) and  (digits!=x[j][0] and digits!=x[j][1] and decade!=x[j][2] and decade!=x[j][3]):
            count+=1
        elif (hundred==x[j][0] or hundred==x[j][2] or hundred==x[j][3]) and (digits==x[j][0] or digits==x[j][1] or digits==x[j][2]) and (thousand!=x[j][0] and thousand!=x[j][1] and thousand!=x[j][2] and thousand!=x[j][3]) and  (decade!=x[j][0] and decade!=x[j][1] and decade!=x[j][2] and decade!=x[j][3]):
            count+=1
        elif (decade==x[j][0] or decade==x[j][1] or decade==x[j][3]) and (digits==x[j][0] or digits==x[j][1] or digits==x[j][2]) and (thousand!=x[j][0] and thousand!=x[j][1] and thousand!=x[j][2] and thousand!=x[j][3]) and  (hundred!=x[j][0] and hundred!=x[j][1] and hundred!=x[j][2] and hundred!=x[j][3]):
            count+=1
    if count == 5:
        print num
```

Comment: Can you explain how to generate the number X in one sentence ?

Comment: It's a math problem. The inputs were given, and X is the answer.

Comment: For the first part of the script, I would convert the numbers to strings, as it is much easier to iterate them. For the second part, you should give a try to the [NumPy package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html). It makes array operations easier and faster to code and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this as alternative, which performs a recursive search, and eliminates possibilities as it chooses pairs of digits that could be the ones that are correct (but misplaced). If it finds that no solution can be found by processing more of the input, it backtracks and tries the next pair of digits, ...etc.

Once the input has been processed like that to the deepest level of recursion, 4 digits are known, and another recursive search kicks in to assign these 4 digits to the positions that are still possible for them. If this succeeds the function immediately steps out of the recursion returning the found value.

```
def findMatch(guesses):
    def assign(pos, digits, result):
        if len(digits) == 0: return True
        digit = digits[0]
        for j in pos[digit]:
            if result[j] == None:
                result[j] = digit
                if assign(pos, digits[1:], result):
                    return ''.join(map(str, result))
                result[j] = None
        return False

    def recurse(guesses, pos, must):
        if len(must) > 4: return False
        if len(guesses) == 0:
            if len(must) < 4: return False # all digits in solution must be unique
            return assign(pos, list(must), [None, None, None, None])
        digits = list(map(int, guesses[0]))
        permutations = ((0,1),(2,3),(0,2),(1,3),(0,3),(1,2))
        for i, (j, k) in enumerate(permutations):
            (l, m) = permutations[i ^ 1]
            [dig1, dig2, dig3, dig4] = [digits[j], digits[k], digits[l], digits[m]]
            if (len(pos[dig1]) > int(j in pos[dig1]) and 
                    len(pos[dig2]) > int(k in pos[dig2]) and
                    dig3 not in must and dig4 not in must):
                saved = [pos[dig1], pos[dig2], pos[dig3], pos[dig4]]
                # remove possibilities
                [pos[dig1], pos[dig2], pos[dig3], pos[dig4]] = [
                    pos[dig1] - set([j]), pos[dig2] - set([k]), set(), set()]
                found = recurse(guesses[1:], pos, must | set((dig1,dig2)))
                if found:
                    return found
                # backtrack
                [pos[dig1], pos[dig2], pos[dig3], pos[dig4]] = saved
        return False

    return recurse(guesses, [set([0,1,2,3]) for i in range(0,10)], set())

guesses = ['6087','5173','1358','3825','2531']
print (findMatch(guesses))
```

This will find the solution faster than the brute force method you have implemented. This code assumes that the solution must consist of distinct digits -- so without one digit occurring twice.